# how could i import xml list with same name using php domdocument

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

using php domdocument, to import xml file, i can't have the list of "tags"

I have tried multiple way but i can't

xml document :

```
<resource>
  <title>hello world</title>
  <tags>
    <resource>great</resource>
    <resource>fun</resource>
    <resource>omg</resource>
</resource>
```

php :

```
<?php
$url='test.xml';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
$feed = $doc->getElementsByTagName("resource");
foreach($feed as $entry) {
echo $entry->getElementsByTagName("username")->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo '<br>';
echo $entry->getElementsByTagName("tags")->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo '<br>';
}
```

i expect the outpout to be a list like that :
hello world
great
fun
omg

but the actual output is NOT a list the result is a sentence without space :
hello world greatfunomg

Comment: Your XML is invalid : no `</tags>` and I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the PHP but you don't have a `username` tag anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()` returns all descendant element nodes with the specified name. `DOMElement::$nodeValue` will return the text content of an element node including all its descendants.

In your case `echo $entry->getElementsByTagName("tags")->item(0)->nodeValue` fetches all `tags`, access the first node of that list and outputs its text content. That is `greatfunomg`.

Using the DOM methods to access nodes is verbose and requires a lot of code and if you want to do it right a lot of conditions. It is a lot easier if you use Xpath expressions. The allow you to scalar values and lists of nodes from an DOM.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<_>
    <resource>
      <title>hello world</title>
      <tags>
        <resource>great</resource>
        <resource>fun</resource>
        <resource>omg</resource>
      </tags>
    </resource>
</_>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
// create an Xpath instance for the document
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch resource nodes that are a direct children of the document element
$entries = $xpath->evaluate('/*/resource');
foreach($entries as $entry) {
    // fetch the title node of the current entry as a string
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $entry), "\n";

    // fetch resource nodes that are children of the tags node
    // and map them into an array of strings
    $tags = array_map(
      function(\DOMElement $node) {
          return $node->textContent;
      },
      iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('tags/resource', $entry))
    );

    echo implode(', ', $tags), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hello world 
great, fun, omg
```

Comment: seems great thank you
but xml is a file, not in my server... and i can t modify it
so i need to load(url) :/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to output the first piece of text for each `<resource>` element - wherever it is, then using XPath and (making sure you ignore whitespace on load) pick the first child element of this and output the node value.

Ignoring the whitespace on load is important as the whitespace will create nodes for all the padding around each element and so the first child of each `<resource>` element may just be a new line or tab.

```
$xml = '<root>
    <resource>
      <title>hello world</title>
      <tags>
        <resource>great</resource>
        <resource>fun</resource>
        <resource>omg</resource>
      </tags>
    </resource>
</root>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
// $doc->load($filename);   // If loading from a file
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$resources = $xpath->query("//resource");
foreach ( $resources as $resource ){
    echo $resource->firstChild->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output of which is

```
hello world
great
fun
omg
```

Or without using XPath...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
//$doc->load($filename);

$resources = $doc->getElementsByTagName("resource");
foreach ( $resources as $resource ){
    echo $resource->firstChild->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```